# How to prove Post's Theorem by induction?

Tags: logic, induction, propositional-calculus, alternative-proof

The proof of post's theorem is given in my textbook in two pages of explanation using a non-induction method. I was told that ,using induction on length of the proof, one can get a simpler and more concise answer.
Here is where I got stuck in finding the proof using this method:

- Since the proof states that if $\Gamma \vdash$ formula(A) is a tautology then $\Gamma$ $\vdash$ A, its contra-positive is the that if $\Gamma$ proves A is not
  provable then $\Gamma$ does not prove A is a tautology. This is assuming $\Gamma$ is the set of all the given hypotheses.
- Base case is when length of proof is 1:
  I know that if A $ \in \Gamma$ then $\Gamma$ $\vdash$ A. But I don't know what could disprove A in a proof of length 1.  I can list the cases in which $\neg$A is proved and therefore A is disproved but I am not very confident in this method.

If I have all the base cases I am confident that I can finish the rest of the proof but I'm still stuck at the beginning.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can see Wiki's entry on [Propositional calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propositional_calculus) : Sketch of completeness proof.

Comment: It is not clear t me the role of induction; if we want to prove that : it $\Gamma \vDash A$, then $\Gamma \vdash A$, the induction is on what ?

Comment: induction on the length of the proof.

Comment: But induction on the lenght of the proof works to prove that : if $\Gamma \vdash A$, then $\Gamma \vDash A$. Fo the other way, we have not yet the proof of $A$ ...

Answer (score 7):

See George Tourlakis, [Mathematical Logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470280743) (2008), page 93 :

> **3.2.1 Metatheorem (Post's Tautology Theorem)** : If $\Gamma \vDash_{TAUT} A$, then $\Gamma \vdash A$.
>
> *Proof*. It is most convenient to prove the *contrapositive*, namely, if $\Gamma \nvdash A$, , then $\Gamma \nvDash_{TAUT} A$

Some *facts* are needed :

**Claim One**. There is an enumeration $G_0,G_1, \ldots$ of all formulae of propositional logic.

See page 95 :

> Assume the hypothesis side, $\Gamma \nvdash A$.
>
> We next construct a set of formulae, $\Delta$, which is as large as possible with the
>   properties that it includes $\Gamma$, but also
>
> > $\Delta \nvdash A$.
>
> We build $\Delta$ by stages, $\Delta_0, \Delta_1, \ldots$ by an *inductive definition*, adding no more than one formula at each step.
>
> The $\Delta_n$ sequence is:
>
> > $\Delta_0 = \Gamma$
>
> For $n \ge 0$ :
>
> > $\Delta_{n+1} = \Delta_n \cup \{ G_n \}$, if $\Delta_n \cup \{ G_n \} \nvdash A$
> >
> > $\Delta_{n+1} = \Delta_n \cup \{ \lnot G_n \}$, if $\Delta_n \cup \{ \lnot G_n \} \nvdash A$
> >
> > $\Delta_n$, else.
>
> Thus, at each stage we add to the set that we are constructing at most one formula, which is a member or a negation of a member of the sequence $\{ G_n \}$.
>
> We define $\Delta = \bigcup_{n \ge 0} \Delta_n$, forming $\Delta$ as the set of all the members found in all the $\Delta_n$.

Several facts follow :

> **Claim Two**. $\Gamma \subseteq \Delta$.
>
> **Claim Three**. For $n \ge 0, \Delta_n \nvdash A$. This follows by induction on $n$.
>
> **Claim Five**. $\Delta \nvdash A$.
>
> **Claim Six**. For every formula $B$, either $B \in \Delta$, or $\lnot B \in \Delta$, but not both.
>
> **Claim Seven**. $\Delta$ is *deductively closed*, that is, if $\Delta \vdash B$, then $B \in \Delta$.

Now we can define a *valuation* $v$ that verifies $\Gamma \nvDash A$.

> Define a *valuation* $v$ by setting, for each variable $p$, $v(p) = t$ iff $p \in \Delta$.
>
> **Main Claim**. For all formulae $B, v(B) = t$ iff $B \in \Delta$.
>
> The proof is by *induction on the complexity* of $B$. We have the following cases:
>
> *(i)* $B$ is a variable : by definition of $v$.

*Then, check all cases according to the inductive definition of formula.*

> After that, we can easily conclude the proof as follows: By the **Main Claim**, every
>   formula $B \in \Delta$ — and hence every formula $B \in \Gamma$ since $\Gamma \subseteq \Delta$ — satisfies $v(B) = t$.
>
> On the other hand, as $\Delta \nvdash A$ it must be $A \notin \Delta$; thus, again via the **Main Claim**, $v(A) = f$. Therefore $\Gamma \nvDash_{TAUT} A$.

See page 99 :

> **3.2.2 Corollary**. If $\vDash B$, then $\vdash B$.
>
> *Proof*. Case of $\Gamma = \emptyset$.

---

*Note*

A different kind of proof of the **Completeness Theorem** for propositional logic (due to Kalmar, 1935) can be found in Elliott Mendelson, [Introduction to mathematical logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0412808307) (4ed - 1997), page 42; also in this case it is required the proof of a lemma by induction on the complexity of the formula.

Comment: I have the textbook and this lengthy proof is exactly what I wanted to avoid. However, I did find the proof I was looking for on the wiki page you gave earlier. You can prove the base with a truth table and then carry out an induction on the complexity of the A. I think that was the answer  I was looking for.